# Rails 4 Model associations - promo code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is for a shopping cart. I'm trying to apply a discount to the total price of the order using a promo code.

I want to focus on these 3 models for now:
1. order
2. promo_code
3. promo_rules

When the order is created, an empty promo code is created as well. Like any other shopping cart, the user can enter the promo code at checkout.

**in order model:**

```
  def create_promo_code
    PromoCode.create(order_id: self.id) 
  end
```

Separately I'm creating promo rules with a "rule code" and "amount" fields.

**promo_rule.rb**

```
class PromoRule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :promo_codes
end
```

The goal is that when the user enters the promo code, it get compared to the "rule code field" of all the promo rule records in the database and if it matches one, then that promo rule gets associated with the promo code. Then the "apply_promo" boolean in the promo code gets updated to true.

**see the update_prom_code here**

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :order
    belongs_to  :promo_rule
    after_update :update_promo_code


    def update_promo_code
        if self.promo_code.present?
            @promo_rule = PromoRule.where("rule_code = ?", self.promo_code).take
            self.promo_rule_id = @promo_rule
            self.apply_promo = true
        end

    end
end
```

**In the order model:**

```
  def apply_promo_code
    if self.promo_code.present? && self.promo_code.apply_promo?
      self.promo = self.promo_rule.amount
    end

  end
```

Here I'm trying to check if the promo code exists and apply_promo is true, then the order promo amount gets updated with the promo rule amount associated with both the promo code and the order.

In other words, once the promo code has been associated with a promo rule, the promo rule "amount" gets deducted from the order total. Make sense?

**also in the order model:**

```
  def total
    if self.promo == nil
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping + tax
    else
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping - promo + tax     
    end
  end
```

**What is NOT working:**
The update_promo_code in the promo_code model

I hope that I'm explaining my goal clearly. I know it's kind of confusing.

Here are the models:

**promo_code.rb**

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :order
    belongs_to  :promo_rule
    after_update :update_promo_code


    def update_promo_code
        if self.promo_code.present?
            @promo_rule = PromoRule.where("rule_code = ?", self.promo_code).take
            self.promo_rule_id = @promo_rule
            self.apply_promo = true
        end

    end
end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :products, through: :order_items
  has_one :shipping_address, through: :user
  has_one :purchase
  has_one :promo_code
  has_one :promo_rule, through: :promo_code
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_create :set_order_user
  before_save :update_subtotal
  before_save :update_total
  before_update :update_subtotal
  before_update :update_total  
  before_save :tax  
  before_save :shipping
  after_create :create_promo_code
  before_update :apply_promo_code



  def apply_promo_code
    if self.promo_code.present? && self.promo_code.apply_promo?
      self.promo = self.promo_rule.amount
    end

  end


  def update_order_promo
    self.touch  
  end

  def create_promo_code
    PromoCode.create(order_id: self.id) 
  end


  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end

  def tax
    shipping_subtotal = shipping + subtotal
    self.tax = shipping_subtotal * 0.07
  end

  def shipping
    self.shipping = 5
  end 



  def total
    if self.promo == nil
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping + tax
    else
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping - promo + tax     
    end
  end  


private
  def set_shipping_address

  end

  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end
  def set_order_user
    self.user_id = user_id
  end  

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end

  def update_total
    self[:total] = total
  end  

end
```

**promo_rule.rb**

```
class PromoRule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :promo_codes
end
```

If you need to see more, let me know and I'll update the question.

Comment: Can you try to strip it down. Way to much code to read. Have you tried on the console (if it fails there as well, you can strip the controllers from the question). Also: i see callbacks. IMHO this is the beginning of a painful mess.

Comment: I've removed the controllers. I've tried on the console in if I manually assign the promo rule id to the promo code and change apply promo to true, then it works.  Do you think this is the beginning of a painful mess because I'm using callbacks  or too many of them? Thank for your help

Comment: Well, if it works on the console and not in the controller, then the controllers are probably needed to find the problem. Sorry for the confusion.  What I'm not clear is what exactly the problem is. What do you mean by "Not working"? Callbacks lead, IMHO, to unreadable code where you are not sure if you can save an object or if a callback triggers some other code that you did no expect.

Comment: Cleaning up: remove all code that is not relevant to the problem. Associations, methods, callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I figure it out.

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: In the promo_code model: I removed the _id from self.promo_rule_id. That solved the problem

Comment: Although that solved the problem at that moment, I ended up changing the logic. I'll post the new model as the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To have it working the way I wanted, I had to change the logic. So I moved the update_promo_code method to the PromoCode model. I think it's much cleaner this way.
**Here are the updated models:**

**promo_code.rb**

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :order
    belongs_to  :promo_rule
    before_update :update_promo_code

    def update_promo_code
        if PromoRule.where(["rule_code = ?", self.promo_code]).first
            @promo_rule = PromoRule.where(["rule_code = ?", self.promo_code]).take
        else
            @promo_rule = PromoRule.find(2)
        end

        if self.promo_code == @promo_rule.rule_code
            self.promo_rule = @promo_rule
            self.apply_promo = true
            self.order.update_attribute(:promo, @promo_rule.amount) 

        else
            self.promo_rule = @promo_rule
            self.apply_promo = false
            true
            self.order.update_attribute(:promo, @promo_rule.amount)

        end
    end

end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :products, through: :order_items
  has_one :shipping_address, through: :user
  has_one :purchase
  has_one :promo_code
  has_one :promo_rule, through: :promo_code
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_create :set_order_user
  before_save :update_subtotal
  before_save :update_total
  before_update :update_subtotal
  before_update :update_total  
  before_save :tax  
  before_save :shipping
  after_create :create_promo_code


  def create_promo_code
    PromoCode.create(order_id: self.id, apply_promo: false) 
  end


  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end

  def tax
    shipping_subtotal = shipping + subtotal
    self.tax = shipping_subtotal * 0.07
  end

  def shipping
    self.shipping = 5
  end 



  def total
    if self.promo == nil
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping + tax
    else
      self[:total] = subtotal + shipping - promo + tax     
    end
  end  


private
  def set_shipping_address

  end

  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end
  def set_order_user
    self.user_id = user_id
  end  

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end

  def update_total
    self[:total] = total
  end  

end
```